# Comparing more than two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean

I want to have a boolean numpy array `fixidx` that is the result of comparing numpy arrays `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. For example I have the arrays

```
a = np.array([1, 1])
b = np.array([1, 2])
c = np.array([1, 3])
d = np.array([1, 4])
```

so the array `fixidx` has the values

> fixidx = [1, 0]

My approach was

```
fixidx = (a == b) & (b == c) & (c == d)
```

This works in Matlab but as it turns out Python only puts out a ValueError.

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

`any` or `all` won't do the trick or at least I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Code works perfectly with no errors. Try `((a == b) & (b == c) & (c == d)).astype(int)` to get `[1,0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code works perfectly with no errors. Try converting boolean output to integer:

```
((a == b) & (b == c) & (c == d)).astype(int)
array([1, 0])
```

Comment: You're right, it works perfectly fine. Strange. I can't explain why I got this error message.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by stacking `a`, `b`, `c` and  `d` into a single array `x`:

```
In [452]: x = np.stack([a, b, c, d])

In [453]: x
Out[453]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 4]])
```

Then you can apply NumPy's [unique](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to each column and test whether the result has one or more elements.

```
In [454]: fixidx = np.array([np.unique(x[:, i]).size == 1 for i in range(x.shape[1])])

In [455]: fixidx
Out[455]: array([ True, False])
```

Finally you can cast `fixidx` to integer if necessary:

```
In [456]: fixidx.astype(int)
Out[456]: array([1, 0])
```

Alternatively, you could obtain the same result through NumPy's [equal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html) as follows:

```
fixidx = np.ones(shape=a.shape, dtype=int)
x = [a, b, c, d]
for first, second in zip(x[:-1], x[1:]):
    fixidx *= np.equal(first, second)
```